# how to make these 2 JSON files communicate?

Tags: python, json

I have this python code where "Employee" is a variable.

Whenever I search for a company in my first JSON file, it gives me the responsible employee and assign it's name to "EMPLOYEE" variable.

In another JSON file, i have a list of the employees with their address and emails.

What I want is, whenever an employee is fetched using the first JSON file, I would want the second file to get on board, and pulls his email + home address.

**Context:**

*Context*: A company wants an appointment, so we check who's free to assign this company a calendar slot.

*Users Job :* insert a date, time, and company name.

*Purpose of the code:* each company in my file has 3 assigned employees to it, by order (1st JSON file). The code will check the first one, then check in my google calendar if he's busy, if he is, it will check the second one...and so on.

```
 # Reads the json data
    with open('convertcsv.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        employeesChosen = []
        event_email = 'abc@abc.com'
        event_start = '2020-05-9T13:00:00'
        event_end = '2020-05-09T15:00:00'
        employeeInsert = False

        # Adds all the current employees for the company picked
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i]['name_enterprise'] == event_fabricant:
                employeesChosen.append(data[i]['employee1'])
                employeesChosen.append(data[i]['employee2'])
                employeesChosen.append(data[i]['employee3'])
                location = data[i]['location']
                print("Employees found")
                break
```

Comment: you can simply use a database which stores and retrieves json data.

Comment: i only have 2 json files, and theyre small. @ZabirAlNazi

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi here you go!

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Still waiting :D

Comment: 1. Your question has some subjective aspect 2. Your given code is not nearly complete or reproducible 3. Calendar checking seems overhead and unrelated to the title 4. We are only able to help if the question is concise, clear, and needs specific solution, we can't code a mini-project which may not meet all the features and be useful for other users later.

Comment: My question is simple. I have 2 JSON files. Example : in one of the files, theres information about Company ABC, in the second JSON file, theres other information about Company ABC. If i pull data from the 1st JSON file concerning Company ABC, how do i retrieve data of Company ABC that is in the second JSON file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data change trigger *some other* action, you'll need *command/script*. If you have them in a git repo, you could use a kind of [git-hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Or any **cron jobs** to check the content of the first file and do something out of the second file (e.g. getting the email and address).

Comment: isn't there another solution?